# Custom jQuery script automatically adding copy button to <pre> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using WordPress and inside it and I'm using a custom WordPress theme. Above jQuery code is causing the issue. If I add `<pre>` element it automatically adds a copy button to the `<pre>` element. I want some `<pre>` elements to have the copy button and I want some of them to not have the copy button and just show the code.

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  var copyid = 0;

  $('pre').each(function() {
    copyid++;
    $(this).attr('data-copyid', copyid).wrap('<div class="pre-wrapper"/>');
    $(this).parent().css('margin', $(this).css('margin'));
    $('<button class="copy-snippet">Copy</button>').insertAfter($(this)).data('copytarget', copyid);
  });

  $('body').on('click', '.copy-snippet', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    var $copyButton = $(this);

    $pre = $(document).find('pre[data-copyid=' + $copyButton.data('copytarget') + ']');
    if ($pre.length) {
      var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");

      // Place in top-left corner of screen regardless of scroll position.
      textArea.style.position = 'fixed';
      textArea.style.top = 0;
      textArea.style.left = 0;

      // Ensure it has a small width and height. Setting to 1px / 1em
      // doesn't work as this gives a negative w/h on some browsers.
      textArea.style.width = '2em';
      textArea.style.height = '2em';

      // We don't need padding, reducing the size if it does flash render.
      textArea.style.padding = 0;

      // Clean up any borders.
      textArea.style.border = 'none';
      textArea.style.outline = 'none';
      textArea.style.boxShadow = 'none';

      // Avoid flash of white box if rendered for any reason.
      textArea.style.background = 'transparent';

      //Set value to text to be copied
      textArea.value = $pre.text();

      document.body.appendChild(textArea);
      textArea.select();

      try {
        document.execCommand('copy');
        $copyButton.text('Copied').prop('disabled', true);;
      } catch (err) {
        $copyButton.text('FAILED: Could not copy').prop('disabled', true);;
      }
      setTimeout(function() {
        $copyButton.text('Copy').prop('disabled', false);;
      }, 3000);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: "$('pre').each(function() " is adding button after each pre tag, if you want to add button to particular pre you need to specify some other identifiers as well.

Comment: @AqibJaved Actually, I don't know JQuery. I'm famaliar with Vanilla JS. Can you please tell me how can I add the copy button to only some <pre> tags I want

Comment: You need a way to identify those elements first, like a ```data-..``` attribute or css class.
Then, inside the ```$('pre').each()```, add a condition like ```if ($(this).hasClass('copyable')) {...}``` or ```if ($(this).attr('myAttr') === True) {...}``` and put the relevant copy button code in there.

Comment: Ok, @Shrimp I'll try and let you know!

Comment: @Shrimp Thank you so much it worked. However, The copy btn is not appearing anymore but the code is being copied somehow.

Comment: _Element_, not tag. Tags are just text in a file.

Comment: @Shrimp, answers go down there.